# Neighbor discovery in contiki

Tags: contiki

> Actually i dont know how to deal with neighbor_recv function. I am not receiving any packet, as was receiving in broadcast-example. All values used in this code are randomly initialized. Moreover I want to store neighbor of each node. Currently I am having 3 telosb motes.

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "net/rime/rime.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "node-id.h"
#include "dev/button-sensor.h"

#include "dev/leds.h"

#include <stdio.h>

struct adv_msg {
  uint16_t val;
};


    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---*/
PROCESS(neighbor_process, "Neighbor example");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&neighbor_process);
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---*/



static void
neighbor_recv(struct neighbor_discovery_conn *c, const linkaddr_t *from)
{
printf("message received from %d.%d: '%s'\n",
         from->u8[0], from->u8[1], (char *)packetbuf_dataptr());
}

static const struct neighbor_discovery_callbacks cb ={neighbor_recv};


static struct neighbor_discovery_conn neighbor;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(neighbor_process, ev, data)
{
  static struct etimer et;
  clock_time_t initial=0;// randomly initialize these values
  clock_time_t min=0;
  clock_time_t max=10;

  uint16_t val=108;

  PROCESS_EXITHANDLER(neighbor_discovery_close(&neighbor));

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  neighbor_discovery_open(&neighbor, 129,initial,min,max,&cb);

  while(1) {

    /* Delay 2-4 seconds */
    etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND * 4 + random_rand() % (CLOCK_SECOND * 4));

PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

packetbuf_copyfrom("Hello", 5);
   neighbor_discovery_set_val(&neighbor,val);
   neighbor_discovery_start(&neighbor,val);
    printf("message sent\n");

 }

  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Hi Olcay, this is the code i have